# How to convert dtype from '0' to 'int64'?

Tags: python, pandas

I started working with a dataset, which is a collection of murder reports.There is a column "Perpetrator Age" in which there are simple integers. But when I looked at his type, it turned out that he was `dtype('O')`.

In order to work with this column further, I want to change its type to `dtype('int64')`. I tried to do it like this:

```
data['Perpetrator Age'] = data['Perpetrator Age'].astype(int)
```

and got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-50a3c796ab1e> in <module>()
----> 1 data['Perpetrator Age'] = data['Perpetrator Age'].astype(int)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    972         # work around NumPy brokenness, #1987
    973         if np.issubdtype(dtype.type, np.integer):
--> 974             return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
    975 
    976         # if we have a datetime/timedelta array of objects

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe()

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

I saw advice for the "object" type, which must first be converted to a string, and then to "int". Tried it, it didn't work either, same error appeared. Please tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: `data['Perpetrator Age'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Perpetrator Age'], errors='coerce')`? You've not specified _how_ you want to address the space (`' '`) characters in this column.

Comment: @HenryEcker but there are no spaces in this column, there is an ordinary integer in each cell

Comment: That is not true since the error message clearly indicates that there is a `' '` character -> `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '` You could always filter the column `print(data.loc[data['Perpetrator Age'].eq(' '), :])` to see where the issue is.

Comment: @HenryEcker Thank you, it turned out that this is the very first line in which the column name is. So I need to somehow remove it in order to work with the rest of the data, now it's all clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the first row of your df is apparently an empty space (`' '`). You can either remove it, replace it with something else, or skip it:

```py
df['column_1'].iloc[1:].astype('int')
```